# How to make an NSMenu recent list

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

I'm working on a small URL shortening application for someone, and I need to have a list, similar to that of Droplr's, that has all of the recently shortened URLs. The list should be a submenu of the main menu, which is attached to an NSStatusItem.

I need to have that list add an item each time a URL is shortened, and I'd like to have a notification come up with the link in it when clicked. The list should have no more than about ten recent URLs.

I also need to have a way to store the list so that it will come up when the app is started again. I don't think it would be a good idea to use Core Data for it, but I'm not sure of what I should use.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to have that list add an item each time a URL is shortened, …

You definitely should [do that](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenu/addItemWithTitle:action:keyEquivalent:).

> … and I'd like to have a notification come up with the link in it when clicked.

As long as the notification says “Copied [short URL] to the clipboard”, since the notification wouldn't be useful otherwise.

> The list should have no more than about ten recent URLs.

Sounds good. You could make this configurable in a Preferences panel.

> I also need to have a way to store the list so that it will come up when the app is started again.

I agree.

> I don't think it would be a good idea to use Core Data for it, but I'm not sure of what I should use.

Core Data may be overkill, but it could work. The other way would be to store it in a plist file, using [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/) to convert your array of (completely custom) model objects to plist data.

Comment: I meant most of what I said as a question, but thank you anyway. I'll be sure to check the documentation next time I have a problem like this too. I usually do, but I felt like I couldn't do it.

I guess my main problem was on how to store the list and load it when the app comes up. Droplr does it in its preferences PList, so I'll try that.